# Using colab to run tflite-model-maker prompts insufficient disk space

Tags: google-colaboratory, tflite

When I use colab to run the image classification example, when I run to the command: !sudo apt -y install libportaudio2
!pip install -q tflite-model-maker, it took a long time to install dependent packages, and finally reported an error because of insufficient hard disk space, my hard disk has 107.7G, why is it not enough to install dependent packages, what should I do? Is it useful to upgrade colab pro?

It prompts that the disk space is insufficient, upgrade pro or delete files, what should I do?